# Intel VTune - Estimate data offload to GPU

Tags: memory, gpu, intel-vtune, offloading

I'm interested in estimate the data transfer, in terms of bytes, of an algorithm or function to be executed on a GPU using Intel VTune. For example, if my algorithm computes a multiplication between two vectors of 10 floats elements each, the result after the offloading would be: 10+10 float elements sent to the GPU and 1, the result, is sent back, so we have 84 bytes in total (21*4). Keep in mind that I'm interested in an estimation, not the actual result on a GPU, since I don't have one available.

With Intel Advisor is possible to do so and is called "Estimated data transfer with reuse", as I attach in the following screen:
[Intel Advisor Data estimation result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G2MQ.png)

In Intel VTune the only way I found is via the "Memory Access" analysis but It express the result as number of loads and stores and probably using hardware counters, so if there are multiple readings from main memory caused by huge data structures, they will be taken into account and does not returns the number of bytes.
[Intel VTune Memory access analysis results example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fllAu.png)

Is there a way to perform a similar analysis with Intel VTune? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have a core CPU in your system, it will have UHD graphics. When you try GPU offload using the Intel Vtune profiler, you can see GPU memory access (read and write) metrics in GB/sec. I have attached a screen shot for your reference. To try GPU offload analysis, you need to have a sample that runs on GPU as well as a system with Intel GPU.

[image]

You can find the answer to your question [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Analyzers/Intel-VTune-Estimate-data-offload-to-GPU/m-p/1425149#M22639).